# How to hook drupal commerce line item create

Tags: commerce

I want to process something when a new commerce line item create, is there any hook can do this?

Or is there another methods can do this?

Thanks at first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at [this](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!line_item!commerce_line_item.module/function/commerce_line_item_hook_info/7) (hook_hook_info()) hook implementation in [commerce_line_item.module](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21commerce%21modules%21line_item%21commerce_line_item.module/7), it exposes `commerce_line_item_insert` which gives you a chance to process some operations on insert operation..

You can use it like this:

```
function MYMODULE_commerce_line_item_insert($line_tem)
{
  // dpm($line_item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use

- [`hook_entity_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_insert/7)

  > Act on entities when inserted.
- [`hook_entity_presave()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_presave/7)

  > Act on an entity before it is about to be created or updated.

Comment: Thank you also, though I don't test, but I think this hook should also can fix my problem. But the hook_commerce_line_item_insert will be more suitable to me this time.